# How to chech for collision between a only part of a sprite with another sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision

Okay, the question is simple. How do i use rectangle collision for only part of a sprite in pygame. Till now, I have this code for player class

```
class Player(sprite.Sprite):        #player object class
def __init__(self,x,y):
    sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    #Groups for Movements
    self.dx,self.dy,self.frame= 0,0,0
    self.vel,self.cushion = 15,5
    self.vmap,self.rvel,self.vrmap=0.7*self.vel,self.vel*2.5,self.vel*2.5*0.5
    self.mapx,self.mapy = 0,0
    self.oldx,self.oldy = 0,0
    self.collide,self.running=False,False
    self.Sback,self.Sfront,self.Sleft,self.Sright = [],[],[],[]
    self.Wfront,self.Wback,self.Wright,self.Wleft=[],[],[],[]
    self.Rfront,self.Rback,self.Rleft,self.Rright=[],[],[],[]
    self.CWfront,self.CWback,self.CWleft=[20,26,1],[7,13,1],[33,39,1]
    self.CRfront,self.CRback,self.CRleft=[14,20,1],[1,7,1],[27,33,1]
    self.Wfront = self.loadimages(self.Wfront,self.CWfront)
    self.Wleft = self.loadimages(self.Wleft,self.CWleft)
    self.Wback = self.loadimages(self.Wback, self.CWback)
    self.Rback=self.loadimages(self.Rback,self.CRback)
    self.Rleft=self.loadimages(self.Rleft, self.CRleft)
    self.Rfront=self.loadimages(self.Rfront, self.CRfront)
    for i in range(0,len(self.Wleft)):
        img =transform.flip(self.Wleft[i],True,False)
        self.Wright.append(img)
    for i in range(0,len(self.Rleft)):
        img =transform.flip(self.Rleft[i],True,False)
        self.Rright.append(img)
    self.Sfront.append(image.load('lib/Images/Fair as Ice/13.gif').convert())
    self.Sleft.append(image.load('lib/Images/Fair as Ice/26.gif').convert())
    self.Sback.append(image.load('lib/Images/Fair as Ice/0.gif').convert())
    self.Sright.append(transform.flip(self.Sleft[0],True,False))
    self.stillimg = self.Sfront
    self.image = self.Sfront[0] #BY DEFAULT, PLAYER WILL HAVE THIS IMAGE(STAND LOOK FRONT)
    self.imagerect=self.image.get_rect()
    self.surface=Surface([self.imagerect.w,self.imagerect.h/3.5]) #surface for collision
    self.rect = self.surface.get_rect()
    self.imagerect.x,self.imagerect.y = x,y

def update(self):        #function is executed every frame by objlst group
    if self.running:
        self.vmap=self.vrmap
    else:
        self.vmap=self.vel*0.9
    if self.input() != 1 or self.input() != 2 or self.input() != 3 or self.input() != 4:
        self.frame+=1
        if self.input() ==1 and self.collide==False:        #checking return value of keyboard input to scroll
                                                            #map and animate player and check if player is colliding
                                                            #with anything
            self.mapx-=self.vmap
            self.stillimg = self.Sleft
        elif self.input()==2 and self.collide==False:
            self.mapx+= self.vmap
            self.stillimg = self.Sright
        elif self.input()==3 and self.collide==False:
            self.mapy -= self.vmap
            self.stillimg=self.Sback
        elif self.input()==4 and self.collide==False:
            self.mapy += self.vmap
            self.stillimg=self.Sfront
    if self.input()==0:
        self.frame=0
        self.image = self.stillimg[self.frame]
    self.oldx,self.oldy=self.imagerect.x,self.imagerect.y   #FOR COLLISION
    self.input()        #taking keyboard value
    if self.imagerect.x<self.mapx+self.cushion and self.collide==False:
        self.imagerect.x=self.mapx+self.cushion
    if self.imagerect.y<self.mapy+self.cushion and self.collide==False:
        self.imagerect.y=self.mapy+self.cushion
    if self.imagerect.x>=self.mapx+scrw-self.imagerect.w and self.collide==False:
        self.imagerect.x=self.mapx+scrw-self.cushion-self.imagerect.w
    if self.imagerect.y>self.mapy+scrh and self.collide==False:
        self.imagerect.y=self.mapy+scrh
    self.imagerect.x += self.dx
    self.imagerect.y += self.dy
    self.rect.x,self.rect.y=self.imagerect.x,self.imagerect.y+2.5*self.imagerect.h/3.5
    #INSERT COLLISION DETECTION HERE:
    for npc in downLayer or upLayer: #downayer and upLayer are sprite groups
        if sprite.collide_rect(self, npc):
            print('hello!')
    self.dx,self.dy=0,0
```

Here, if the player class collides with a NPC, it prints 'hello', but what i want is to only print 'hello' when self.surface collides with NPC.
Also, is it possible to use bitmask collision for this?

(when i try to use self.surface for collision,it gives me an error.self.surface has no rect attribute.) I was hoping that collide_rect uses self.rect to cleck for collisio, but apparently thats not the case.
So, how do i check for collision between self.surface and npc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pygame.Rect.colliderect(Rect)](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

```
# self.surface.get_rect().collidrect(another_rectangle)

self.surface.get_rect().collidrect(npc.rect)


self.surface.get_rect().collidrect(another_surface.get_rect())
self.surface.get_rect().collidrect(some_sprite.rect)
self.surface.get_rect().collidrect(pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height))

another_surface.get_rect().collidrect(self.surface.get_rect())
some_sprite.rect.collidrect(self.surface.get_rect())
pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height).collidrect(self.surface.get_rect())
```

Surface has no attribute `.rect` (`self.surface.rect`), it use method `.get_rect()` (`self.surface.get_rect()`) but `collide_rect()` required object with attribute not method. `pygame.Rect.colliderect()` required object `Rect` so you can use `surface.get_rect()` or `sprite.rect` as argument.

BTW: with `pygame.Rect` you can detect collision with single point `pygame.Rect.collidepoint`